# No implicit conversion of Enumerator into Array

Tags: ruby, syntax, operator-precedence

I have:

```
qs = ["all=true", "limit=-1"]
value = ["agent", "service", "token"]
```

This code:

```
qs.concat value.map do |val|
  "#{field}=#{val}"
end
```

ends up with the following error:

```
`concat': no implicit conversion of Enumerator into Array (TypeError)`
```

whereas this code:

```
values = value.map do |val|
  "field=#{val}"
end
qs.concat values
```

does not.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: `values.each { |val| qs << "field=#{val}" }` – no need for a temporary array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the different precedences when providing blocks to chained method calls. In your case you use the following code:

```
qs.concat value.map do |val|
  "#{field}=#{val}"
end
```

Ruby assumes here that you mean the following:

```
qs.concat(value.map) do |val|
  "#{field}=#{val}"
end
```

That is, Ruby passes the block to the first method (i.e `qs.concat`) which ignores the block. Since `Array#map` [returns an `Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) if you don't pass a block, you get your error you saw.

To solve this, you can use the braces form of passing the block, i.e.:

```
qs.concat value.map { |val|
  "#{field}=#{val}"
}
```

In this form, the block is always passed to the "last" method, u.e. your `map`.

In any case, if there is any doubt about operator precedence, it is always a good idea to use explicit parenthesis or intermediate variables to make it clear both to human readers as well as the Ruby interpreter how your code is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `qs.concat value.map do |val|`, what does `do` belong to? (Hint: not `value.map`!)

Use parentheses when uncertain.

```
qs=["all=true", "limit=-1"]
value=["agent", "service", "token"]
qs.concat(value.map do |val|
  "field=#{val}"
end)
```

`{...}` would be more typical than `do...end`, and the priority works out so you don't actually need parentheses, as `{...}` do go to `value.map` rather than to `qs.concat`. This also works:

```
qs=["all=true", "limit=-1"]
value=["agent", "service", "token"]
qs.concat value.map { |val|
  "field=#{val}"
}
```